# Report Test Case Names for @TestFactory

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I have a Junit `@TestFactory` method, and I would like to create a report of all the test case names. This is easily viewed in Eclipse, but I would also like to do some text processing on the names at the command line. Is there any way that I can get this reported by Surefire at the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement and register a custom [TestExecutionListener](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom).

For example, you could implement something similar to the following.

```
package my.example.package;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.Type;
import org.junit.platform.engine.TestExecutionResult;

public class DynamicTestListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    private final Set<TestIdentifier> dynamicTests = Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<>());

    @Override
    public void dynamicTestRegistered(TestIdentifier testIdentifier) {
        if (testIdentifier.getType() == Type.TEST) {
            this.dynamicTests.add(testIdentifier);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        if (this.dynamicTests.contains(testIdentifier)) {
            System.out.println(testIdentifier.getDisplayName());
        }
    }

}
```

The above example can be automatically registered via Java's `ServiceLoader` mechanism by putting the following in `src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` (or under `src/main/resources` if you are publishing a library):

```
my.example.package.DynamicTestListener
```

Comment: Sure. I'll add that now.

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: You can have it registered automatically via Java's `ServiceLoader` mechanism. See the documentation in the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: Update: I tried out the proposed listener, and it works as advertised.

Comment: Great. I did not notice that; I was expecting some type of code example in the docs, but I guess if it is automatic, I won't see any. :-)

Comment: I am confused about the "automatic" configuration. It is not as simple as just having it in the classpath, I assume, since it is not working yet. Please provide an example of the configuration.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss, I see you figured it out on your own and updated my answer for me. Congrats and thanks!